# How to perform a validation on an attribute only if the value of the attribute is not null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validation

I have a search criteria for a Project model. A Project can be searched using an id or project name.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ProjectSearchCriteria {
    @IsNumberValidatorConstraint(message = "invalid input for id")
    private String id;
    private String projectName;
}
```

I have also created a custom validator to check whether the id is a number (Number validation). This is also working perfectly.

But my question is that is there any possibility for me to tell spring; to perform Number validation only if id is not null?

e.g:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/projects?id=1 (id needs to be validated)

http://localhost:8081/api/projects?projectName=project1 (No need to validate the id)
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you add `if(value == null) return true;`  to your custom validator? Which makes it valid if the id is null.

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom validator to return true if number and also for null.

```
public class IsNumberOrNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsNumberValidatorOrNullConstraint, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String number, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        if(number == null){
            return true;
        }
        return NumberUtils.isParsable(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. but i thought the question was to have spring not do the validation if it was null. this actually *does* the validation but returns true if it's null.